# Как в Sublime Text 3 увеличить шрифт на вкладках?

Tags: sublime-text-3

За шрифт текста файлов отвечает класс 
"font_size".
Интересует есть ли класс, который может изменить размер шрифта во вкладках?[image: на картинке обвел красным]

Answer (score 1):

Установите пакет [PackageResourceViewer](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer).
Нажмите `ctrl + shift + P`.
Введите `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource`.
Выберите свою тему, например, "Theme - Default".
В появившемся списке выберите "Default.sublime-theme"
Найдите там описание класса "tab_label" и добавьте туда свой "font.size" (не забудьте добавить запятую):

```
{
    "class": "tab_label",
    "fg": [152, 152, 152],
    "shadow_color": [0, 0, 0, 0.25],
    "shadow_offset": [0, -1],//запятую не забудьте
    "font.size": 24
}
```

Сохраните документ.
Если шрифт оказался большим и текст не вмещается по высоте,
то найдите в этом же документе класс "tabset_control", 
и измените в нем параметр "tab_height":

```
// Tabs
{
    "class": "tabset_control",
    "layer0.opacity": 1.0,
    "content_margin": [4, 0, 8, 0],
    "tint_index": 0,
    "tab_height": 34,//<--вот этот параметр
    "tab_overlap": 16
}
```

Сохраните документ.